# Transparent proxy and udp load balance with Nginx in Docker

Tags: nginx, iptables, docker, udp, transparent-proxy

I'm trying to setup udp load balancer with  IP and port transparent proxy.
My environment runs on docker. We are using mesos + marathon to manage containers. 
For UDP load balancing I use Nginx. App and Nginx runs in docker containers.
I have few requirements: 1. One client should always connect to the same app  node during his session. 2. App behind nginx should assume that it is  communicating  to the client directly.

I used this article for my setup: https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/

So nginx is running with root user. Containers are on the same network.
I've included a bunch of modules for nginx like stream and  nginx-sticky-module-ng  and etc.

Nginx Stream conf: 
`

```
upstream app-server {
  sticky;
  server some-app:5684;
  server some-app:5684;
 }

server {     
    listen 5684 udp;
    proxy_pass app-server:5684;
    proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
    proxy_responses 1;
    proxy_timeout 1s; 
       }
```

On Each upstream server I set default gw to Nginx IP.

On nginx I set following iptables rules.

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -s 172.16.0.0/16 --sport 5684 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 0 #I assume this should be 0,because there could be different ports
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

But client can't reach the server it seems. It looks like packets just got stuck on the Nginx. Am I missing some configuration or something wrong with iptables rules?